# Entity Framework DbContext: entities configured every time?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I'd like to know if Entity Framework `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` gets configured each time it's instantiated.

*Why I got this question?*

For example, if you're doing manual mappings overriding `DbContext.OnModelCreating(...)` method, it seems that this is going to be called each time a `DbContext` is instantiated.

**Does Entity Framework perform some kind of configuration caching or whatever?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configured model is cached.

> The EDM used by Code First for a particular context type is cached in
>   the app-domain as an instance of DbCompiledModel.

See [Code First: Inside DbContext Initialization](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/) for more info

Comment: Let's see what's in that link!

Comment: Pay attention to the fact I'm not using an auto-generated EDMX or model, but I want to directly use `DbContext` and configure mappings using `DbContext`'s fluent interface. **Does this apply to my case too?** Thanks! :)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes. The blog post describe the process used in Code First model initialization. If it is not sufficient you can go through the [source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/)